# Push notification to apple device with no certificate file

Tags: java, ios, ssl, push-notification

I want to write an application which takes application id and certificate of my client's app registered in APNS server and tries to push a notification to the concrete device in his name. I should recieve the data from my client in JSON form. The problem is I can't make him to send me a certificate in JSON. 
I would like to use this method call later:

Push.alert("Hello World!", "keystore.p12", "keystore_password", false, "Your token");

Is there a way to do this without .cer file? Can client of mine send me just some text information to fill in place of "keystore.p12", "keystore_password"?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use push notifications through apple without a certificate. You should get the certificate from your client through some secure means and not through a service that is part of your app. A certificate, such s this, has a private key and should be guarded as it can be used to impersonate your server. If your client will not give you the certificate, either a development cert or a production cert, and you need to continue working on his project, you should create an entirely different app id for testing and when you get to a point where you are distributing to your client, change to the app id of you client.